Bolding the values in just one column of the matrix
I am trying to format the values in just one column of a Power BI matrix visual so that the values this column are bold, but don't see an option to do this.  I am able to change the font color as well as the background color of the column, but don't see an option for bolding the text in the column.  Is this possible and how?  I've seen some posts about html but nothing that provided a solution
I clicked on conditional formatting of the font, but I don't see an option for making the text bold. I see an option for changing the font color, but nothing to make it bold

I don't believe it is possible in a matrix, I use an add on called Power KPI Matrix that allows me to format the columns bold.
